# How to find entry-point typedef for a given PE?

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

I wrote a simple function which will execute a given executable from memory. My question is, after I have resolved the import table, rebased the image, and parsed the PE sections. I am unable to execute `any given` executable.

By `any given` I mean, I want to figure out how to know the entry-point type definition on-the-fly. Lets say my test executables entry-point has the following type

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HMODULE base, HMODULE prev, LPSTR cmd, INT windowstatus);
```

so the `typedef` would be accordingly

```
typedef INT (WINAPI *WinMain)(HMODULE, HMODULE, LPSTR, INT);
```

But what if the entry-point of the executable isn't defined like that;

1. How can I know which parameters it takes and pass them accordingly on the fly, and execute the image?
2. Also, how can I find out how a given executables entry-point typedef would look like (manually)?

Currently I have the above `typedef` but the executable I want to execute crashes after calling the entry-point, hence it's obviously not defined like that.

**ADDITIONS**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyxJA.png) I have the entry-point for a given executable in IDA-PRO with softICE

I'm assuming the `mov` instructions refer to the arguments passed to the entry function. But how can I know in which order they come and what data-type is assigned to each so I can typedef it?

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add this function to it.

Comment: No reason to do that (my function has no value in the question, theres no issue (crash/bug)), I'm just asking how can I find the typedef for any given PE on-the-fly. Manually and/or automatically.

Comment: WinMain is not executed as first. You have a lots of startup before that. \

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Omg I know that dude, CRT and stuff (WinMainCRTStartup) and critical sections ... BUT THIS IS NOT WHAT IM ASKING!!!! Guys, please, I'm just asking how to find out which datatypes a given entry point has and how can I find them out? Take a look at the `ADDITIONS` section and click the `here` href. You will see.

Comment: @G63 AMG you are rude dude.

Comment: You are telling me things that I already know, why am I rude?

Comment: it is not your entry point in your disassembly. You get to the exception handling init. But because you know everything and are rude - I will not give you more hints. Bye

Comment: The only information contained in the executable is the Win32 entry point.  Assuming the program uses a runtime, the application entry point could be anywhere; Windows neither knows nor cares.  You would have to reverse-engineer the runtime to figure this out, doing so automatically would be extremely difficult and far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  But why do you want to find the application entry point in the first place?  You don't need it in order to run the executable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Because I want to run it from memory

Comment: For that you only need the Win32 entry point, which always has the same signature.  Calling the Win32 entry point launches the runtime, which will in turn call the application entry point, e.g., WinMain.  Calling the application entry point directly wouldn't work anyway, because the runtime wouldn't be initialized.

Comment: @RbMm, the entry point does get a pointer to the PEB, but that argument is typically ignored by Windows applications, which have no use for it.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, this is really true. and usually this is argument ignored. because it or not need for applications. or who use *PEB* get it by `RtlGetCurrentPeb()` or from *TEB*. so must be `void __stdcall ep (PEB* peb)`